# Converting spatial slots to lists

Tags: r, list, geo, r-sp

I have a SpatialLinesData frame with 1657 different routes.  Each route is of a different length and has a differing number of nodes or waypoints (lat, lon).

For example, `routes@line[[87]]` is made up of 7 waypoints.  I am wondering if there is a simple method to extract the lat, lon coordinates, or [,1] and[,2] of every route and convert them into a list of 1657.

When I try this with one `routes@line[[87]]`, for example, I get an error:

```
> as.list(routes@lines[[87]])
Error in as.list.default(routes@lines[[87]]) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

Does a method exist for converting line objects to lists?

```
> str(routes)
Formal class 'SpatialLinesDataFrame' [package "sp"] with 4 slots
  ..@ data       :'data.frame': 1657 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ start_time: Factor w/ 1631 levels "2016/09/09 00:00:02",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  .. ..$ duration  : int [1:1657] 786 1248 738 786 651 660 616 889 408 475 ...
  .. ..$ difftime  :Class 'difftime'  atomic [1:1657] 2 4 19 67 92 119 170 202 206 213 ...
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "secs"
  ..@ lines      :List of 1657

> routes@lines[[87]]
An object of class "Lines"
Slot "Lines":
[[1]]
An object of class "Line"
Slot "coords":
          [,1]     [,2]
[1,] -79.92976 43.25867
[2,] -79.92984 43.25865
[3,] -79.92986 43.25868
[4,] -79.92989 43.25870
[5,] -79.92983 43.25871
[6,] -79.92983 43.25871
[7,] -79.92983 43.25871



Slot "ID":
[1] "87"
```

Comment: Might be worth looking at [`library(sf)`](https://github.com/edzer/sfr), which is the update to `library(sp)`. You can convert `sp` objects to `sf` using `sf::st_as_sf()`, and each line will be represented as a list, in a single row of a `data.frame`

Comment: Might also be worth looking at `routes@lines[[87]]@line[[1]]@coords` - that is where the coordinate matrix resides, given that the lines object has only a single line.